# Vertical-align of img interfering on div height

Tags: html, css

I have an image of *24x24 px* inside an `<a>`, which is nested in a `<div>` having `min-height:50px`.

The bottom and top paddings of `<a>` element are *13px* both.

So, height should be *24px*(image height) + *13px*(`<a>` padding-top) + *13px*(`<a>` padding-bottom) = *50px* right?

The problem is that the wrapper `<div>` is expanding its height to 54px, except when I define the `vertical-align:middle` for that image, then It's resized to 50px as desired.

Here is the code http://codepen.io/thyagosic/pen/JKYrjN

Removing the `vertical-align: middle;` may help to understand the problem

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation as to why using `vertical-align: middle` (instead of `vertical-align: baseline`) leads to a different height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All images are inline elements by default and they have 4px space at the bottom. You should set 'vertical-align:top' or 'display: block' on them to remove this space.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting images inside of links into divs (or setting `display: block` to the element)

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="image"> 
      <img src="http://xamlspy.com/Media/Default/Logo/XamlSpy.24x24.white.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Also padding/margin should be set for "block" elements